# How long can $DISPLAY environment variable value be?

Tags: environment-variables, linux-headers

What is the maximum length that $DISPLAY environment variable value can take?

I understand that it is -  hostname:displaynumber.screennumber

So will it be => max($DISPLAY) = max(hostname) + max (displaynumber) + max(screennumber)?

What is max length of hostname, displaynumber and screennumber on Linux?

Comment: You have asked four different questions. I don't know about the hostname, but you almost certainly won't run into any issues with the DISPLAY variable being too long. There is probobly a limit, but you won't hit it with normal use.

Comment: I understand that. I need to know the limit though as I will be persisting this information. I cannot assign something too big (as I have limited space) and i cannot assign something too less that it does not gets captured completely in some cases.

Answer (score 5):

Environment variable length is controlled by `MAX_ARG_STRLEN`, which is a constant value defined as `PAGE_SIZE*32` [within the Linux kernel](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/binfmts.h).

You can check your `PAGE_SIZE` value via Terminal like this:

```
getconf PAGE_SIZE
```

If you are running stock Ubuntu (or an official flavour), then the value will likely be `4096` (bytes).

So, with this in mind:

```
4096 * 32 = 131,072
```

As a result, the maximum length of an environment variable, be it `$DISPLAY` or any other, is 128KB. This works out to 131,072 single-byte ASCII characters.

Comment: Thanks @matigo. This is too big and potentially defines the length in general for all environment variable. I am interested particularly in $DISPLAY environment variable. How big can it get?

Comment: I suggest re-reading the first seven words of the answer. *All* environment variables have the same limit. Linux is not like George Orwell's *Animal Farm*; there are no environment variables that are more equal than others 