# Is there a size limit on NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS?

Tags: scripts, python, nautilus

I'm experiencing some strange behaviour with a Python script that I wrote for Nautilus.

It's well located, +Xed and functions well with a "smalllist of files" (around 1000).

When I select more than a certain numer of files, the script does not lauch, as if there was alimit on the size of the list passed to my script through NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS.

Above a certain number of files, the script does not lauch anymore.

Is there a known size limit on NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS ?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion !

Context :
The script sorts my family pictures according to picture date in subdirectories [YYYY-MM] style. Because there are more than 100,000 pictures to dispatch, I found intgeresting to doit by scripting.

I make some weird usage of Tk to follow the progress. Be gentle, I'm a beginner ;-)

Here's the script I wrote :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys, os, datetime

import tkinter as tk

def main(args):

    # tk related
    global text, fen
    def ecrire(texte):
        text.insert(tk.INSERT, texte + "\n")
        text.see('end')
        fen.update_idletasks()

    fen = tk.Tk()
    fen.geometry("600x350")
    fen.title("Process monitor")

    # zone de texte dans la fenêtre
    text = tk.Text(fen, height=20, width=80)
    text.pack()

    for path in os.getenv('NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS','').splitlines():
        ecrire(path)

        # get file modification date as datetime object
        fstamp = os.path.getmtime(path)
        fdate = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(fstamp)
        ddir = fdate.strftime("[%Y-%m]")

        basedir = os.path.dirname(path)
        destdir =os.path.join(basedir, ddir)

        destpath = os.path.join(destdir, os.path.basename(path))

        # ensure destdir exists and handle duplicates
        os.makedirs(destdir, exist_ok=True)

        i=0
        while os.path.exists(destpath):
            x1, x2 = os.path.splitext(destpath)
            i += 1
            destpath = x1 + "_(" + str(i) + ")" + x2

        os.rename(path, destpath)
        ecrire(" -> " + destpath)

        ecrire("\nClose window [X] to terminate")

    fen.mainloop()

    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
```

Comment: Probably related to the maximum length of an environment variable: https://askubuntu.com/a/1385554/855322

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a documented limit, but since `NAUTILUS_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS` is an environment variable, the contents will be limited by the maximum size allocated in the system for storing environment variables.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't consider it under this angle, but it's obviously what's limiting me.